# Flutter Hot Reload not reloading/refreshing assets

Tags: dart, flutter

When I add an Image asset to my project and later change the image file in the asset directory without changing its filename, it doesn't update in the app. I've tried hot reload, full restart, uninstalling and reinstalling app, flutter clean, `gradle` clean. All not working, even invalidate and restart android studio, still not working.

Comment: You could try uninstalling the app from the device/emulator. I have seen one or two similar issues been reported but can't remember if or how they fixed it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I already stated that I've uninstalled and reinstalled on the device, still not working

Comment: Are you running on a device or emulator? Android or iOS?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm running on a device

Comment: Did you run `flutter packages get` ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet, yh I already did, flutter packages get, flutter packages upgrade, flutter upgrade, flutter doctor, all of it (except uninstalling and reinstalling flutter, lol), :(

Comment: In my case I had moved the old asset to a subdirectory (assets/old/image.png) keeping the same filename, and the build was including it as a variant image (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-variants) and somehow choosing it over the new one.

Answer (score 20):

I understand you are updating asset files without changing image name and you are wondering how to tell flutter to reread your asset.

I had the same problem, making small changes to json file included as an asset.

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
flutter run
```

Works for me

Comment: As posted in the question, flutter clean didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: @Suhas a bit painful, but you could try `git clean -X` to remove temporary files that are ignored by git.

Answer (score 3):

No need to delete the directory, flutter clean etc. All you need is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

...

imageCache.clear();
```

Flutter caches images behind the scene, so if you change the image, you either need to rename it, or use this to clear the cache.

Comment: does this applies to `json` files as well? all `assets`?

Comment: This only applies to images. If you're using rootBundle to load assets, that also uses a cache - you have to use `await rootBundle.evict(key)` to clear the cache for a specific asset

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I deleted the entire directory and recreated it, but this time I made sure that only assets used and related to the project was added to the directory. Hopefully this helps anyone with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

simply call this

```
flutter clean &&
flutter packages get && 
flutter run
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation of what this exactly does