# Flutter Hot Restart not reloading .html asset file

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) in my Flutter project.
I load html asset file into InAppWebView:

```
...
InAppWebView(
    initialFile: "assets/html/index.html",
    initialSettings: settings,
),
...
```

If I change local file assets/html/index.html - there is no effect after Hot Restart.
So I need to completely restart project.

Is it possible to change local asset html file without restarting project?

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427453/flutter-hot-reload-not-reloading-refreshing-assets), but it is about asset images. Clearing image cache not working in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Hot Reload not reloading/refreshing assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427453/flutter-hot-reload-not-reloading-refreshing-assets)

Comment: @Yash no. "flutter clean && flutter packages get && flutter run" rebuilds a project, but it takes long time. I want to get effect quickly, right after Hot Restart.
"imageCache.clear()" not working in my case.